# Is it possible to find out which NUMA system memory bank the current thread belongs to?

Tags: multithreading, jvm, hardware, numa

I'm writing a NUMA-aware algorithm and need this information for optimal memory keeping. It would be nice if you know a solution for JVM(for example using oshi), but I can't find it even for C/C++

Comment: Threads do not "belong to a NUMA system memory bank". Or what do you mean by this?

Comment: Thread belong to processor and  processor in NUMA system has the closest memory bank, and I want somehow know id of it.

Comment: I want to have unique instance of object (for example array) in each memory bank and use it from threads which processor is closest to it, for example for flat combining .

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible because of abstraction levels (physical processors and logical processors), if it's impossible please tell me.

Comment: Threads are not tied to a particular CPU. Once you get the "current" CPU using, for example, [`sched_getcpu`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html) call, the very next moment the OS may migrate your thread to another CPU. You can assign a thread to a specific CPU with [`sched_setaffinity`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html), but if you do so, you already know the mapping between a thread and a CPU yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Threads are not bound to a given core by default** (so not to a NUMA node). Thus, it does not make sense to get the NUMA node of a thread since it can switch from once node to another at any time. If your threads are bound to cores or at least to NUMA nodes (possibly using `taskset` or a pthread system call on Linux for example), then this is possible but AFAIK it is not possible in Java, but possible in C though it is *certainly not portable*.

On Linux, in C, you can get the current CPU of a running thread using **`sched_getcpu()`**. Note that AFAIK a "CPU" does not mean a micro-processor but a core or even an hardware thread in practice (this is what can be seen in `/proc/cpuinfo` for example). Then, you can use **libnuma** so to get the NUMA node information. More specifically, the `numa_node_of_cpu` function should give you the NUMA node of the target CPU.

The only portable C library I known which is able to do that is **`libhwloc`** (which uses libnuma internally on Linux). You can get more information about it [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) and [there](https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v2.8.0/index.php).

AFAIK controlling the NUMA allocation policy from the JVM is not possible in general (especially if threads are not bound). If threads are bound (done manually) and the JVM performs local allocation (very likely but not garanteed), then the default **first-touch policy** (which can be tuned by `numactl` on Linux and may be a different one on some platforms) should map the pages of the referenced data on the NUMA node doing the write.